# How to check scrolling direction of OSX with cocoa APIs

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I can't find out if scrolling is set to reverse mode or not currently, and I want to show that setting and also use this for sliders and stuff.

I know I can check just check the plist:

```
dict = open("/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist");
=> dict.objectForKey("com.apple.swipescrolldirection");
```

I am looking for any API here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [**`isDirectionInvertedFromDevice`**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSEvent/isDirectionInvertedFromDevice) property on `NSEvent`.

Answer (score 5):

I came across the same problem just now, this is how I solved it:

**Edited with Catfish_Man’s suggestions:**

```
NSString *scrollDirection = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"com.apple.swipescrolldirection"] boolValue]? @"Natural" : @"Normal";
```

Comment: You don't need to -synchronize first. That will just slow your app down and accomplish nothing. Also, the global domain is in the default search list, so you don't need to use persistentDomainForName, you can just use objectForKey.