# OS X Double-Click Speed

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, core-graphics

Is there any way of retrieving the double-click speed from the System Settings, preferably using C++ (CG APIs perhaps), otherwise an Objective-C example would also be acceptable.

I found that it's possible to get the scrolling direction using `standardUserDefaults`, but I haven't been able to find any documentation for this:

[How to check scrolling direction of OSX with cocoa APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433018/how-to-check-scrolling-direction-of-osx-with-cocoa-apis)

Note: I'm not looking for a Cocoa-specific solution. E.g. I don't think it's possible to retreive `NSEvent.doubleClickInterval` from a **non-cocoa application**. I might be wrong though.

Comment: What does this have to do with Core Graphics?

Comment: Core Graphics contains, among many other things, all of the Quartz Event Service API, which is quite relevant regarding mouse movement: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html

Comment: Ah, the old Carbon APIs. I didn't think anyone used those anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently HIToolbox has been deprecated and is not available for 64-bit applications. It seems the best solution is to link to the AppKit framework and wrap the Objective-C call doubleClickInterval of the NSEvent class. This works even for non-cocoa C++ applications just fine.

**Linker Flags:**

```
-framework AppKit
```

**Foo.cpp:**

```
#include "Utility.h"

void foo()
{
    double doubleTimeInCppApp = GetDoubleTime();
    ...
}
```

**Utility.h:**

```
double GetDoubleTime();
```

**Utility.mm:**

```
double GetDoubleTime()
{
    return [NSEvent doubleClickInterval];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is here:

```
defaults read -g com.apple.mouse.scaling
```

Ooops, that is the tracking speed... hold on.

Comment: I might be this: `com.apple.mouse.doubleClickThreshold` but I'm uncertain if I'll be able to get this value from a non-cocoa application...

Comment: There is GetDblTime() function also.

Comment: Do you know what library that function is defined in? I can't find any documentation for it. :/

Comment: It's in Carbon... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Events.h

Comment: Just found it myself as well :)

Comment: Isn't GetDblTime() deprecated by now..?

Comment: Yes, after asking around on the Mac dev forums I was told that the HIToolbox has been deprecated and is not available for 64-bit applications.